# Yeoman and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express, yeoman

I want to know if there is some boilerplate code to use a frontend workflow tool like Yeoman with a backend framework like ExpressJS, if I want to maintain the same codebase for both the front and back ends.

Basically I want to know -

- How do the boilerplate code produced by yeoman and express fit in together. Is there a way to integrate the two? (How does the gruntfile fit into the express project)
- Can I substitute yeoman's default watch with an express server which reloads pages on update?

Comment: I've tinkered with this a little bit, but only enough to discover I don't have the knowledge required to tackle the integration of the two projects. I've recruited a friend and NodeJS expert, and together I hope to provide some boilerplate Express/Yeoman code to the Yeoman community.

Comment: please do post a link to the code once you are done! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yeoman is currently focused on front-end app development, but we're going to explore back-end integration in the future.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually there isn't any right now.

But you can combine [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) with the [component package manager](https://github.com/component/component). There is some work left, and you cant use yeoman components in component.

To answer your questions

- You can look for components in the component repo that you have used in yeoman. Not the same, but might be a solution.
- Use the module [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) for this. You can get it via npm

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an easy way of integrating my own Express + H5BP + Angular + Grunt skeletons into Yeoman, and eventually just settled for creating a repo here: https://github.com/ericclemmons/genesis-skeleton

From what I've read, there are projects underway to add express generators, but eventually stacks are going to get complex enough to where you'll have to maintain your own starter app, rather than generating it.

Answer (score 1):

There's an experimental branch with yeoman + express.js [G+ Yeoman/Express Article](https://plus.google.com/115133653231679625609/posts/YDNbxVxi4er%20Seems%20promising.)

I found yeoman.js to be very cool for rapid prototyping but does require some ramping up to get used to the various tools it's "opinionated" about. I've decided to go over each of the core tools in some vids that are hopefully helpful: [yeoman.js related videos](https://plus.google.com/115133653231679625609/posts/YDNbxVxi4er)

Answer (score 1):

[Yoeman fullstack](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack) generator now generates both front end and back end. Other interesting frameworks which do the same are [Sails JS](http://sailsjs.org/) and [StrongLoop](http://strongloop.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting there is an `express-generator` project:

- [official docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)
- [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express)

I am going to give it a go - because I'm folling [this tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/#.Vwwq1WcrKkA) - but other than that I cant comment on its value.